# How to R/W file in android system directory (Internal Storage)

Tags: java, android, busybox

- I want to create the file in android system folder.
- I have also tried this "mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2
  /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system" using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() but
  it's not working.

  if you have example please let me know.
  Thanks

Comment: type adb shell check if # is there it will work if $ is there you cant.

Comment: I don't think I'd want any app doing that to **my** phone ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android applications don't run as `root` on an unmodified device so they can't write to the `/system` folder or remount file systems.

Why do you want to write to `/system`?  What's wrong the the storage directory for you app?

[This may be possible on a "rooted" Android device](http://androidsu.com/superuser/) but this rules out the majority of users.

Comment: i want replace the existing file. i m creating app that change the font

Comment: That's definitely not possible on a phone that hasn't been rooted.  Follow the link in my answer to read about using Superuser on a rooted phone.

Comment: this is possible using the shell command have a look [link](http://shreyagarwal.blog.com/2011/04/20/executing-shell-commands-in-android-applications/).

Comment: If you look at the link the first command run is `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“su”);` **which requires a rooted android device**.  This `su` is the Superuser app I linked you to in my answer.

Comment: i knew the su(super user) su is not enough i want example

Answer (score 0):

//if its showing as **$** you need to root your phone

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb shell
$
```

//if its showing as **#** you can copy files

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb shell
#
```

//let do this step

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$  adb root
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb remount
```

//push a file from you system to your phone

```
  adb push ./Desktop/my_lib.so  /system/lib
```

Comment: this is using terminal i want to achieve this using android program

Comment: @Padma Kumar Is it possible to write files to system folder on an Android Developer's Phone with rooting?