# commands running on simulator not on android phone

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, android-binder

I ran the ad shell on my simulator and executed the following commands:-

```
cd /proc
cd binder
cat transaction_log
```

But when i ran the adb shell on my android phone and ran the following commands

```
cd /proc
cd binder
```

**HERE I GOT AN ERROR SAYING CAN"T cd to BINDER**

Can anyone tell what the problem is?

Comment: you might need root permission to do this. it will work in Emulator but not on phones.

Comment: check your phone is rooted or not http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736810/1012284

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the `/proc/binder/` folder does not exist on your phone...

Comment: Then the folder exists on your friend's phone but not yours

Comment: i ran the following code FILE *trans1;             trans1=fopen("/proc/binder/transcation_log","r");
 if(trans1==NULL)
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"Tarun99","cannot open trans1 file error %s", strerror(errno)); i am not able to see the file but if i run through adb shell i am able to view that file